# Как найти текст между двумя словами?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется строка, "Обеспечение высокой степени жизнестойкости компании посредством бесперебойной работы подразделения". Нужно найти весь текст между словом "степени" и "бесперебойной", средствами js. Итог "жизнестойкости компании посредством".
Пробовал со сплитом, регуляркой.

```
let name = 'Обеспечение высокой степени жизнестойкости компании посредством бесперебойной работы подразделения'

let before = name.split('бесперебойной')[0].replace(/name=(.+)/, "$1")

let name2 = name.split('степени').pop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const str = 'Обеспечение высокой степени жизнестойкости компании посредством бесперебойной работы подразделения'

console.log(str.match(/степени (.*) бесперебойной/)[1]);
```